# How do i use Double Datatype in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

please help me ............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Number.

```
var foo:Number = 10.232321131;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jammin,

if you are incorporating Java with flex,
use 'D'ouble as datatype in java, as values passed as 'd'ouble or float from java to Flex will be rounded off or altered.

Happy Coding